# Backoffice errors after di:compile and deploy

Tags: error, admin-panel, magento2.4.4

After manually removing some files into `pub/static/frontend` (because the cache wasn't cleaning properly, neither with bin/magento cache:clean/flush nor from the backoffice) and then cleaning and flushing the cache from CLI I got a blank page without errors when trying to load my Magento e-commerce or the backoffice.
I solved the ecommerce problem with

- bin/magento setup:di:compile
- php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
- bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
- bin/magento cache:clean
- bin/magento cache:flush

But now for what concerns the backoffice, every time I try to load the admin uri it says:

```
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #1 [ <required> Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PublicCookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory ] of Magento\Security\Model\SecurityCookie class
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PublicCookieMetadataFactory does not exist
```

I tried to understand what it is but I can't figure it out...

Magento version: 2.4.4
Server distro: Ubuntu 20.04
PHP: 7.4

Comment: Try to disable all third extensions first and then check by enabling one by one. So you get idea if that occurs from any party extension or not.

Comment: I don't know what it was exactly but somehow I solved it: I wanted to do some tests without breaking more stuff, so I decided to clone everything on another server to make my tests. I dumped the DB, changed the IPs in core_config_data and uploaded it on the other server, I copied the entire Magento root folder, pasted it on the server and changed the DB data in env.php. On the new server I compiled the DI, set developer mode and re-deployed static-content. Everything was working good. It's not an effective solution to the problem (so I'm not posting this as an answer) but it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having this problem multiple times and doing some tentatives I finally came to a solution.

The problem comes when I delete some of the files generated by magento and I'm logged-in in the backoffice.

When I try to refresh the backoffice page I get the error.

**Solution (simpler than I thought)**
If I clean the cookies and website data in the browser the problem is solved.